# file_get_contents doesn't work on remote host

Tags: php

I need to fetch data from remote host using codes below.

```
$url = 'https://domain.com/cgi-bin/cgi.exe';
$data = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

It works fine on internal network, but not on external network. Firewall has been opened for both port 80 and 443, but still doesn't work. Is there anything else that I miss?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($result);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server must have the allow_url_fopen  property set to true

```
  file_get_contents('http path to file');
```

Comment: The destination server is not running PHP. Do I need to enable it on client host where the script is run?