# I cannot download data from external IP with php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some issues with a custom wordpress plugin I'm developing.
I need to retrieve a text string from two external IP, from one of the two I have no problem at all, the other one doesn't work.

I've used both file_get_contents and cURL but with no success.

for cURL I found this

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;}
```

`$data = file_get_contents_curl(IP.'/file.php');`

With this function, i work great with one IP, the other one has a port specified (like this 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:100) and it won't get the data.

On a local wordpress installation I didn't have any problem with both IP, on a live site the IP with the port doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384581/file-get-contents-doesnt-work-on-remote-host

Comment: I've also checked if  allow_url_fopen is set to true and it is, so I cannot understand why there's this problem